# VBA - Loop Through Filtered Data of Pivot Table

Tags: excel, vba

**Original post was deleted as the context of the question has changed.**

I have a PivotTable that I am trying to filter on and then capture only the filtered data, however, I don't seem to be capturing the correct filter data.

**Here is the original table:**

[image]

**Pivot Table:**

[image]

**Filter Applied:**

[image]

**Pivot Table:**

[image]

No when I run my code, it doesn't capture the data I see that's filtered, it's still reading ALL the date for fk_new_component.

Code:

```
    Sub Results_06_Filter_Pivot_Table(myArray As Variant)

        Set tmpltWkbk = Workbooks("New DB.xlsm")
        Set ws1 = tmpltWkbk.Sheets("Pivot")
        Set PvtTbl = ws1.PivotTables("PivotTable")

'Array of fk_keyword unique values
        myArr = myArray

        Application.ScreenUpdating = False

        PvtTbl.ManualUpdate = True

        Set pvtField = PvtTbl.PivotFields("fk_keyword")

        With pvtField
            .Orientation = xlPageField
            .Position = 1
        End With

        PvtTbl.ManualUpdate = False

        ws1.Activate

        For i = LBound(myArr) To UBound(myArr)

            If i <> 0 Then

                pvtField.ClearAllFilters

                pvtField.CurrentPage = myArr(i)

                With ws1

                    Set compField = PvtTbl.PivotFields("fk_new_component")

                    'For Each PvtItem In PvtTbl.VisibleFields
                    For Each Pi In compField.PivotItems

                        If Pi <> "" And Pi.Visible Then

                            i = i + 1
                            ReDim Preserve arrCompElements(i)
                            arrCompElements(i) = PvtItem.Name

                        End If

                    Next Pi

                End With

            End If

        Next i

        'pvtField.ClearAllFilters

        For Each pvtField In PvtTbl.PageFields
          pvtField.Orientation = xlHidden
        Next pvtField

        Application.ScreenUpdating = True

        PvtTbl.ManualUpdate = False

    End Sub
```

Comment: Doesn't `pvtField.ClearAllFilters` make all items visible? So checking `If Pi <> "" And Pi.Visible Then` essentially becomes `If Pi <> "" Then`

Comment: @Nacorid Thank you for the reply. I checked, but it doesn't clear the filter. The filter is still applied and showing the correct data. Also removed `Application.Screen updating = True` and `PivotTable.ManualUpdate = True`. The statement clears any existing filters but the new filter is applied directly after.

Comment: Have you tried running the code without the line `pvtField.ClearAllFilters`, I honestly don't understand why it's there in the first place. [ClearAllFilters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.pivotfield.clearallfilters) states that all applied filters are removed.

Comment: @Nacorid yes, when you mentioned it that was the first thing that I did - removed it. Ran the code without it but still got the same result. As for why it's there, it's to make sure that the line where I apply the filter, it only has that filter applied. If there are any other filters on the table already, then this will just add to them. Well, that how I understand it anyways... I could be wrong..

Comment: But where are you applying any filter? You only ever delete filters with `pvtFiled.ClearAllFilters` on each iteration through your array.

Comment: @Nacorid I mean it doesn't need to be there I suppose, but currently, with or without it being there, it's not the cause of the issue I have..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190903/discussion-between-nacorid-and-eitel-dagnin).